# Frechet Filter and Principal Filter

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Recall: [Filters](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Filter.html)

- Let $X$ be a nonemty set. Let $A\subseteq X$. Let $F_0$ be frechet filter and let $F(A)$ be principal filter.

If for $A\subseteq X$, $F_0\subseteq F(A)$ , then what can we say?

Comment: Every cofinite set must contain $A$. This could only happen if $A$ is empty. In this case $F(A)$ is the power set of $X$, if you allow filters that are not proper. We could say that if we do not allow a filter to equal the power set of $X$, then the conditions you list cannot happen.

Answer (score 0):

As X a subset of X, F$_0$ subset F(X) = {X}.
Thus every cofinite subset of X is X.
If x in X, then cofinite X - {x} = X, a contradiction.
Thus X is empty, a contradiction that destroys the problem,